# Import data using ECK and feeds module

Tags: entities, feeds

Is it possible to import data from CSV file and insert all in two different entities
for example I have created two different entities, cadidates and exams entities, once I import data to exam entity i would like to make candidat entity updated also referencing to some field, i have tried many solution possible but in vain

Answer (score 0):

Why not make two importers that you run on the same CSV dataset? Run it first on the first imported setup and then again on the next. Each imported can be configured to create the needed content type.